# SQL/Laravel Building a Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I am currently getting quite frustrated with this, I would really appreciate any help!

I have a SQL table that tracks when people click certain buttons on the website. Every time someone clicks the button it creates an event on the table.

What I am currently doing is building a page that shows these stats on a Google Visualization graph. I have got it working but I am 100% sure there is a much quicker and cleaner way of doing this.

**ADDED MORE DETAILS**

I am trying to do is group the database column type, then I want to count the amount per group and display this on the view in a graph. This is currently working but I want to learn how to shorten the function in my controller.

I am new to SQL I have only recently learned the basics so I would appreciate a little bit more guidance.

This is an example of the database:

[database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hwu5.png)

This is the function in the controller

```
public function UsedCarsSearch() {      

    // Used Car Search

    $searchmodeldropdown              = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'search-model-dropdown')->count();
    $searchmanufacturerdropdown       = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'search-manufacturer-dropdown')->count();
    $searchvehiclesbutton             = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'search-vehicles-button')->count();
    $searchfueltypedropdown           = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'search-fuel-type-dropdown')->count();
    $searchtransmissiondropdown       = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'search-transmission-dropdown')->count();
    $searchenginesizedropdown         = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'search-engine-size-dropdown')->count();
    $searchdoorsdropdown              = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'search-doors-dropdown')->count();
    $refinesearchmobilebutton         = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'refine-search-mobile-button')->count();
    $searchseatsdropdown              = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'search-seats-dropdown')->count();
    $searchmaxpricedropdown           = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'search-max-price-dropdown')->count();
    $menulinkmobilemenusearchbutton   = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'menu-link-mobile-menu-search-button')->count();
    $searchmaxmileagedropdown         = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'search-searchbox-dropdown')->count();
    $searchsearchboxdropdown          = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'search-max-mileage-dropdown')->count();
    $searchminpricedropdown           = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'search-min-price-dropdown')->count();
    $searchpostcodedropdown           = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'search-postcode-dropdown')->count();
    $search                           = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'search')->count();
    $searchminmileagedropdown         = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'search-min-mileage-dropdown')->count();
    $searchvehiclesbuttonmobiletop    = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'search-vehicles-button-mobile-top')->count();
    $approvedusedsearchtab            = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'approved-used-search-tab')->count();
    $resetsearchbutton                = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'reset-search-button')->count();
    $newsearchtab                     = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'new-search-tab')->count();
    $servicesearchtab                 = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'service-search-tab')->count();
    $searchminadvancedpaymentdropdown = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'search-min-advanced-payment-dropdown')->count();
    $searchmaxadvancedpaymentdropdown = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'search-max-advanced-payment-dropdown')->count();
    $resetsearchbuttonmobiletop       = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'reset-search-button-mobile-top')->count();
    $searchmaxmonthlypaymentdropdown  = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'search-max-monthly-payment-dropdown')->count();
    $searchminmonthlypaymentdropdown  = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'search-min-monthly-payment-dropdown')->count();


    // Vehicle Spec Interest

    $accordionopenaccordiondriverconvenience    = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'accordion-open accordion-driver-convenience')->count();
    $accordionopenaccordioninteriorfeatures     = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'accordion-open accordion-interior-features')->count();
    $accordionopenaccordionexteriorfeatures     = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'accordion-open accordion-exterior-features')->count();
    $accordionopenaccordionentertainment        = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'accordion-open accordion-entertainment')->count();
    $accordionopenaccordionsafety               = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'accordion-open accordion-safety')->count();
    $accordionopenaccordionsecurity             = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'accordion-open accordion-security')->count();
    $accordionopenaccordionfuelconsumption      = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'accordion-open accordion-fuel-consumption')->count();
    $accordionopenaccordionperformance          = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'accordion-open accordion-performance')->count();
    $accordionopenaccordionwheels               = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'accordion-open accordion-wheels')->count();
    $accordionopenaccordiongeneral              = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'accordion-open accordion-general')->count();
    $accordionopenaccordiontechnical            = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'accordion-open accordion-technical')->count();
    $accordionopenaccordionemissions            = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'accordion-open accordion-emissions')->count();
    $accordionopenaccordionengineanddrivetrain  = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'accordion-open accordion-engine-and-drive-train')->count();
    $accordionopenaccordiontyres                = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'accordion-open accordion-tyres')->count();
    $accordionopenaccordiontrim                 = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'accordion-open accordion-trim')->count();
    $accordionopenaccordionweightandcapacities  = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'accordion-open accordion-weight-and-capacities')->count();
    $accordionopenaccordionvehicledimensions    = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'accordion-open accordion-vehicle-dimensions')->count();
    $accordionopenaccordionpacks                = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'accordion-open accordion-packs')->count();
    $accordionopeninteriorfeatures              = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'accordion-open interior-features')->count();

    // Bodystyle Interest

    $hatchback      = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'hatchback-option-checkbox')->count();
    $estate         = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'estate-option-checkbox')->count();
    $suv            = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'suv-option-checkbox')->count();
    $fourxfour      = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', '4x4-option-checkbox')->count();
    $mpv            = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'mpv-option-checkbox')->count();
    $saloon         = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'saloon-option-checkbox')->count();
    $sport          = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'sport-option-checkbox')->count();
    $convertible    = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'convertible-option-checkbox')->count();
    $coupes         = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'coupes-option-checkbox')->count();
    $pickup         = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'pickup-option-checkbox')->count();
    $crewvan        = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'crew-van-option-checkbox')->count();
    $doublecab      = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'double-cab-option-checkbox')->count();
    $minibus        = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'minibus-option-checkbox')->count();
    $tipper         = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'tipper-option-checkbox')->count();
    $dropside       = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'dropside-option-checkbox')->count();
    $luton          = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'luton-option-checkbox')->count();
    $chassis        = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'chassis-option-checkbox')->count();
    $box            = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'box-option-checkbox')->count();
    $curtainslider  = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'curtainslider-option-checkbox')->count();
    $platformcab    = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'platform-cab-option-checkbox')->count();
    $refridgerated  = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'refridgerated-option-checkbox')->count();
    $freezer        = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'freezer-option-checkbox')->count();


    // Options Interest

    $airconditioning    = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'air-conditioning-option-checkbox')->count();
    $bluetooth          = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'bluetooth-option-checkbox')->count();
    $satnav             = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'sat-nav-option-checkbox')->count();
    $cruisecontrol      = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'cruise-control-option-checkbox')->count();
    $parkingsensors     = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'parking-sensors-option-checkbox')->count();
    $heatedwindscreen   = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'heated-windscreen-option-checkbox')->count();
    $cdplayer           = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'cd-player-option-checkbox')->count();
    $dabradio           = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'dab-radio-option-checkbox')->count();
    $auxinput           = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'aux-input-option-checkbox')->count();
    $parkassist         = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'park-assist-option-checkbox')->count();
    $phonenav           = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'phone-nav-option')->count();
    $heatedseats        = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'heated-seats-option-checkbox')->count();
    $parkingcamera      = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'parking-camera-option-checkbox')->count();
    $leatherinterior    = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'leather-interior-option-checkbox')->count();
    $keylessentry       = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'keyless-entry-option-checkbox')->count();
    $dvdplayer          = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'dvd-player-option-checkbox')->count();
    $metallicpaint      = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'metallic-paint-option-checkbox')->count();
    $mp3player          = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'mp3-player-option-checkbox')->count();
    $spoiler            = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'spoiler-option-checkbox')->count();


    // Image Interests

    $interiorinterests      = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'interior-images-tab')->count();
    $exteriorinterests      = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'exterior-images-tab')->count();
    $featuresinterests      = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'features-images-tab')->count();
    $allinterests           = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'all-images-tab')->count();
    $imagesonlyinterests    = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'images-only-option-checkbox')->count();


    // Sort By Button

    $sortByButton           = UsedCarsAnalytics::where('type', '=', 'sort-bar-dropdown')->count();

    return View::make('reports.used-cars-search', compact(
        'searchmodeldropdown',
        'searchmanufacturerdropdown',
        'searchvehiclesbutton',
        'searchfueltypedropdown',
        'searchtransmissiondropdown',
        'searchenginesizedropdown',
        'searchdoorsdropdown',
        'refinesearchmobilebutton',
        'searchseatsdropdown',
        'searchmaxpricedropdown',
        'menulinkmobilemenusearchbutton',
        'searchmaxmileagedropdown',
        'searchsearchboxdropdown',
        'searchminpricedropdown',
        'searchpostcodedropdown',
        'search',
        'searchminmileagedropdown',
        'searchvehiclesbuttonmobiletop',
        'approvedusedsearchtab',
        'resetsearchbutton',
        'newsearchtab',
        'servicesearchtab',
        'searchminadvancedpaymentdropdown',
        'searchmaxadvancedpaymentdropdown',
        'resetsearchbuttonmobiletop',
        'searchmaxmonthlypaymentdropdown',
        'searchminmonthlypaymentdropdown',
        'accordionopenaccordiondriverconvenience',
        'accordionopenaccordioninteriorfeatures',
        'accordionopenaccordionexteriorfeatures',
        'accordionopenaccordionentertainment',
        'accordionopenaccordionsafety',
        'accordionopenaccordionsecurity',
        'accordionopenaccordionfuelconsumption',
        'accordionopenaccordionperformance',
        'accordionopenaccordionwheels',
        'accordionopenaccordiongeneral',
        'accordionopenaccordiontechnical',
        'accordionopenaccordionemissions',
        'accordionopenaccordionengineanddrivetrain',
        'accordionopenaccordiontyres',
        'accordionopenaccordiontrim',
        'accordionopenaccordionweightandcapacities',
        'accordionopenaccordionvehicledimensions',
        'accordionopenaccordionpacks',
        'accordionopeninteriorfeatures',
        'hatchback',
        'estate',
        'suv',
        'fourxfour',
        'mpv',
        'saloon',
        'sport',
        'convertible',
        'coupes',
        'pickup',
        'crewvan',
        'doublecab',
        'minibus',
        'tipper',
        'dropside',
        'luton',
        'chassis',
        'box',
        'curtainslider',
        'platformcab',
        'refridgerated',
        'freezer',
        'airconditioning',
        'bluetooth',
        'satnav',
        'cruisecontrol',
        'parkingsensors',
        'heatedwindscreen',
        'cdplayer',
        'dabradio',
        'auxinput',
        'parkassist',
        'phonenav',
        'heatedseats',
        'parkingcamera',
        'leatherinterior',
        'keylessentry',
        'dvdplayer',
        'metallicpaint',
        'mp3player',
        'spoiler',
        'interiorinterests',
        'exteriorinterests',
        'featuresinterests',
        'allinterests',
        'imagesonlyinterests',
        'sortByButton'
    ));
```

This is the view blade:

```
@extends('templates/master')

@section('content')

<style type="text/css">
    .analytics-charts {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 32.2%;
        height: 400px;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        vertical-align: top;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: #f5f5f5;
        padding: 20px;
        margin-right: 1.45%;
        margin-bottom: 1.45%;
    }

    .analytics-single {
        display: inline-block;        
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        vertical-align: top;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: #f5f5f5;
        padding: 20px;
        margin-right: 1.45%;
        margin-bottom: 1.45%;
    }
</style>

<h1>Used Car Search Web Analytics</h1>

<div class="analytics-charts">
    <h2>Used Car Search</h2>
    <h3>Click Count</h3>
    <div id="pieChart"></div>
</div>

<div class="analytics-charts">
    <h2>Vehicle Spec Interest</h2>
    <h3>Click Count</h3>
    <div id="pieChartVehicle"></div>
</div>

<div class="analytics-charts">
    <h2>Bodystyle Interests</h2>
    <h3>Click Count</h3>
    <div id="pieChartBody"></div>
</div>

<div class="analytics-charts">
    <h2>Options Interests</h2>
    <h3>Click Count</h3>
    <div id="pieChartOptIn"></div>
</div>

<div class="analytics-charts">
    <h2>Image Interests</h2>
    <h3>Click Count</h3>
    <div id="pieChartImgInt"></div>
</div>

<div class="analytics-single">
    <h2>Sort By</h2>
    <h3>Click Count {{ $sortByButton }}</h3>
</div>

@stop
@section('scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

    <!-- Used Car Search Pie -->
    <script>

        google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {

            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Used Car Search');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Click Count');
            data.addRows([      
                ['Model', <?php echo $searchmodeldropdown ?>],
                ['Manufacturer', <?php echo $searchmanufacturerdropdown ?>],
                ['Vehicles Button', <?php echo $searchvehiclesbutton ?>],
                ['Fuel Type', <?php echo $searchfueltypedropdown ?>],
                ['Transmission', <?php echo $searchtransmissiondropdown ?>],
                ['Engine Size', <?php echo $searchenginesizedropdown ?>],
                ['Doors', <?php echo $searchdoorsdropdown ?>],
                ['Refine Search Mobile', <?php echo $refinesearchmobilebutton ?>],
                ['Seats', <?php echo $searchseatsdropdown ?>],
                ['Max Price', <?php echo $searchmaxpricedropdown ?>],
                ['Menu Link Mobile Menu Search', <?php echo $menulinkmobilemenusearchbutton ?>],
                ['Max Mileage', <?php echo $searchmaxmileagedropdown ?>],
                ['Searchbox', <?php echo $searchsearchboxdropdown ?>],
                ['Min Price', <?php echo $searchminpricedropdown ?>],
                ['Postcode', <?php echo $searchpostcodedropdown ?>],
                ['Search', <?php echo $search ?>],
                ['Min Mileage', <?php echo $searchminmileagedropdown ?>],
                ['Vehicles Button Mobile Top', <?php echo $searchvehiclesbuttonmobiletop ?>],
                ['Approved Used Search Tab', <?php echo $approvedusedsearchtab ?>],
                ['Reset Search Button', <?php echo $resetsearchbutton ?>],
                ['New Search Tab', <?php echo $newsearchtab ?>],
                ['Service Search Tab', <?php echo $servicesearchtab ?>],
                ['Min advanced Payment', <?php echo $searchminadvancedpaymentdropdown ?>],
                ['Max advanced Payment', <?php echo $searchmaxadvancedpaymentdropdown ?>],
                ['Reset Search Button Mobile Top', <?php echo $resetsearchbuttonmobiletop ?>],
                ['Search Max Monthly Payment', <?php echo $searchmaxmonthlypaymentdropdown ?>],
                ['Search Min Monthly Payment', <?php echo $searchminmonthlypaymentdropdown ?>],
            ]);

            var options = {
                title: 'My Daily Activities',
            };

            options.chartArea = {left: 0, 'width': '90%', 'height': '90%'}

            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('pieChart'));

            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>

    <!-- Vehicle Spec Interest Pie -->
    <script>       
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartVehicle);
        function drawChartVehicle() {

            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Used Car Search');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Click Count');
            data.addRows([                      
                ['Driver Convenience', <?php echo $accordionopenaccordiondriverconvenience ?>],
                ['Interior Features', <?php echo $accordionopenaccordioninteriorfeatures ?>],
                ['Exterior Features', <?php echo $accordionopenaccordionexteriorfeatures ?>],
                ['Entertainment', <?php echo $accordionopenaccordionentertainment ?>],
                ['Safety', <?php echo $accordionopenaccordionsafety ?>],
                ['Security', <?php echo $accordionopenaccordionsecurity ?>],
                ['Fuel Consumption', <?php echo $accordionopenaccordionfuelconsumption ?>],
                ['Performance', <?php echo $accordionopenaccordionperformance ?>],
                ['Wheels', <?php echo $accordionopenaccordionwheels ?>],
                ['General', <?php echo $accordionopenaccordiongeneral ?>],
                ['Technical', <?php echo $accordionopenaccordiontechnical ?>],
                ['Emissions', <?php echo $accordionopenaccordionemissions ?>],
                ['Engine and Drivetrain', <?php echo $accordionopenaccordionengineanddrivetrain ?>],
                ['Tyres', <?php echo $accordionopenaccordiontyres ?>],
                ['Trim', <?php echo $accordionopenaccordiontrim ?>],
                ['Weight and Capacities', <?php echo $accordionopenaccordionweightandcapacities ?>],
                ['Vehicle Dimensions', <?php echo $accordionopenaccordionvehicledimensions ?>],
                ['Packs', <?php echo $accordionopenaccordionpacks ?>],
                ['Interior Features', <?php echo $accordionopeninteriorfeatures ?>]
            ]);

            var options = {
                title: 'My Daily Activities',
            };

            options.chartArea = {left: 0, 'width': '90%', 'height': '90%'}

            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('pieChartVehicle'));

            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>

    <!-- Bodystyles Pie -->
    <script>       
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartBodyInt);
        function drawChartBodyInt() {

            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Used Car Search');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Click Count');
            data.addRows([                      
                ['Hatchback', <?php echo $hatchback ?>],
                ['Estate', <?php echo $estate ?>],
                ['Suv', <?php echo $suv ?>],
                ['4x4', <?php echo $fourxfour ?>],
                ['Mpv', <?php echo $mpv ?>],
                ['Saloon', <?php echo $saloon ?>],
                ['Sport', <?php echo $sport ?>],
                ['Convertible', <?php echo $convertible ?>],
                ['Coupes', <?php echo $coupes ?>],
                ['Pickup', <?php echo $pickup ?>],
                ['Crewvan', <?php echo $crewvan ?>],
                ['Doublecab', <?php echo $doublecab ?>],
                ['Minibus', <?php echo $minibus ?>],
                ['Tipper', <?php echo $tipper ?>],
                ['Dropside', <?php echo $dropside ?>],
                ['Luton', <?php echo $luton ?>],
                ['Chassis', <?php echo $chassis ?>],
                ['Box', <?php echo $box ?>],
                ['Curtainslider', <?php echo $curtainslider ?>],
                ['Platformcab', <?php echo $platformcab ?>],
                ['Refridgerated', <?php echo $refridgerated ?>],
                ['Freezer', <?php echo $freezer ?>],                
            ]);

            var options = {
                title: 'My Daily Activities',
            };

            options.chartArea = {left: 0, 'width': '90%', 'height': '90%'}

            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('pieChartBody'));

            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>

    <!-- Options Interest Pie -->
    <script>       
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartOptInt);
        function drawChartOptInt() {

            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Used Car Search');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Click Count');
            data.addRows([                      
                ['Air Conditioning', <?php echo $airconditioning ?>],
                ['Bluetooth', <?php echo $bluetooth ?>],                
                ['Sat Nav', <?php echo $satnav ?>],
                ['Cruise Control', <?php echo $cruisecontrol ?>],
                ['Parking Sensors', <?php echo $parkingsensors ?>],
                ['Heated Windscreen', <?php echo $heatedwindscreen ?>],
                ['Cd Player', <?php echo $cdplayer ?>],
                ['Dab Radio', <?php echo $dabradio ?>],
                ['Aux Input', <?php echo $auxinput ?>],
                ['Park Assist', <?php echo $parkassist ?>],
                ['Phone Nav', <?php echo $phonenav ?>],
                ['Heated Seats', <?php echo $heatedseats ?>],
                ['Parking Camera', <?php echo $parkingcamera ?>],
                ['Leather Interior', <?php echo $leatherinterior ?>],
                ['Keyles Sentry', <?php echo $keylessentry ?>],
                ['Dvd Player', <?php echo $dvdplayer ?>],
                ['Metallic Paint', <?php echo $metallicpaint ?>],
                ['Mp3 Player', <?php echo $mp3player ?>],
                ['Spoiler', <?php echo $spoiler ?>]
            ]);

            var options = {
                title: 'My Daily Activities',
            };

            options.chartArea = {left: 0, 'width': '90%', 'height': '90%'}

            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('pieChartOptIn'));

            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>

    <!-- Image Interest Pie -->
    <script>       
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartImgInt);
        function drawChartImgInt() {

            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Used Car Search');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Click Count');
            data.addRows([                      
                ['Interior', <?php echo $interiorinterests ?>],
                ['Exterior', <?php echo $exteriorinterests ?>],
                ['Features', <?php echo $featuresinterests ?>],
                ['All', <?php echo $allinterests ?>],
                ['Images Only', <?php echo $imagesonlyinterests ?>]
            ]);

            var options = {
                title: 'My Daily Activities',
            };

            options.chartArea = {left: 0, 'width': '90%', 'height': '90%'}

            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('pieChartImgInt'));

            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>
@stop
```

Comment: what's your question again?

Comment: Why so much SQL selects if you can make just one?

Comment: You can use `GROUP BY` SQL clause for this operation.

Comment: eto proto **PIZDEC**

Comment: I would like to shorten all of this.
I am very new to SQL I have only recently learned the basics, so a bit more guidance on how to complete the following would be appreciated.

I want to groupby type and then count every groupby type and put that into a variable where I can then display the count in a graph on the view blade

Answer (score 1):

```
$records = UsedCarsAnalytics::selectRaw('COUNT(id) as count, type')->groupBy('type')->get();
```

You will get object with counf for each type.

```
foreach($records as $record){
    echo $record->type." - ".$record->count."<br>";
}
/* You will get someting like:
search-model-dropdown - 62
search-manufacturer-dropdown - 113
.
.
.
*/
```

Then you can create variables .... what you need. Important is, that you will have only one SQL select, ant it should speed up things.

Comment: Hi Autista,

Thanks for commenting, this did work, it created a list of types with their counts. The problem I have is I need to select 10 of them types and put them into a google graph.

Comment: Well, then just use `->orderBy('column_name')` and `->limit(10)` (both before `->get()`)

Comment: I will edit the above to make it easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest building a query which would produce the sql statement along the lines of

Select Count(type),type from  where type in () group by type

In laravel that can probably be best achieved with a raw expression (DB::raw) 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#raw-expressions

However if your doing this many stats etc also consider looking at a search engine integration solr or elasticsearch has some of these capabilities and will be much quicker

Comment: Thanks, Shaun, I have looked in the raw expressions but I had an issue with retrieving all the counts for all the groups of types. It would list the whole groups but only counted one of the groups. 

But I will have a look into Elasticsearch

Comment: using group by?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so heres my idea, first of all, you should rethink the architecture of your database, for example, make another table named "search types" that will be like this

```
id | search type |
1  | a           |
1  | b           |
2  | c           |
2  | d           |
```

this way, you'll separate the information, it's cleaner trust me, but not necessary

then, try this

```
$items = UsedCarsAnalytics::all();
$data = array();

foreach($items as $item){
   $data[$item->type]++;
}
return View::make('reports.used-cars-search',$data);
```

this way, in your data array, you will have the key as the search type, and the value as the number of searches

if you have tons of search types, but i doubt it, for optimization you can use [SplFixedArray](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php)

Comment: Hi Lessan, 

That table holds 41,533,283 records and it took a few minutes to run this. 

Thanks 
Danny

Comment: then, as already mentioned, you should try to use group by, but if you have so much data in a single table? wouldn't it be a good idea to split it in more tables? have a table and a model for each type for example, and you can define an admin page where you can add this automatically. I don't know if it's a good idea, i'm just a beginner, but more little problems are better than a huge one